# Event fired multiple times on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML button and click event associated to it. The event is occurring multiple times. I tried .off & .unbind also.

```js
$("div.onoffswitch").off().on("click", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Not clear from the original question, but this does occur when there is text inside the `label` (missing from question code).

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue with the provided code: https://jsfiddle.net/e1eesekn/. Could you please show a working example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: where is the button?

Comment: when using checkbox i suggest use `.change()`

Comment: and why are you binding the event for entire div??

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you put the "Click Me" text inside the `label for`, you get the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/e1eesekn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs when text inside the `label for` (inside an extra span or not) is clicked, it raises a click event for the checkbox - this then propagates/bubbles up to the containing div.

`label for` allows you to link a checkbox with related text - click the text and the checkbox is toggled.

You have two options:

- don't use `label for` to link the text+checkbox
- don't use an event on the containing div

If you're trying to allow additional clicks to change the textbox (eg with an image), then don't use `label for`.  But bear in mind that clicking the checkbox itself will toggle if you're then using the event to toggle - so all new issues.

If you're trying to find when the checkbox changes, use `label for` with the `changed()` event on the checkbox (not the div)

Comment: thanks for answer and explanation. Worked perfectly !